# Suggestion for additional tags "Jersey" and "Guernsey"

Tags: discussion, tags

Can we add tags for:

[Jersey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jersey)

[Guernsey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailiwick_of_Guernsey)

To be added to questions such as these

[How did United Kingdom responsibility for the defence of the British Channel Islands originate?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/69495/how-did-united-kingdom-responsibility-for-the-defence-of-the-british-channel-isl)

[Channel Islands Equivalence in Financial Services](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/61007/channel-islands-equivalence-in-financial-services)

[Brexit, EU tax evasion regulation, and the City of London](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/45569/brexit-eu-tax-evasion-regulation-and-the-city-of-london)

Note: The Bailiwick of Jersey and the Bailiwick of Guernsey are collectively known as the British Channel Islands or Channel Islands for short. They have the collective name Channel Islands only because of their geography - they are actually separate countries each with its own government. They are often referred to collectively in the context of relations with the United Kingdom but it seems to me to be better to add two tags **Jersey** and **Guernsey** for a question about "the Channel Islands" rather than have a *British Channel Islands* tag. It also avoids confusion with phrases such as *British Isles* and *British Islands* all of which mean different things but are sometimes confused.

Comment: Why do we need these tags?

Comment: For questions about these countries

Comment: Yes, tags are used for questions but if you are going to suggest new tags you should also include questions where the new tags are needed as tags can't exist without a question that they are on.

Comment: The Bailiwick of Jersey and the Bailiwick of Guernsey are collectively known as the British Channel Islands or **Channel Islands** for short. They have the collective name Channel Islands only because of their geography - they are actually separate countries each with its own government. If you search for **Channel Islands** you will see that there are many questions which are asked about them. These could have the tags *guernsey* and *jersey* added to them.

Comment: Please some questions where the tags can be used

Comment: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/69495/how-did-united-kingdom-responsibility-for-the-defence-of-the-british-channel-isl  https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/61007/channel-islands-equivalence-in-financial-services  https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/45569/brexit-eu-tax-evasion-regulation-and-the-city-of-london

Comment: You need to add those to the question and explain which tag is needed and why.

Comment: How do I "add those to the question"? I get an error message saying that the tags do not exist

Comment: You can't as you don't have enough rep but you can add questions that can make use of the tags and explain why they need them.

Comment: I did that but someone then deleted them saying that they should be added as tags and that the best way to do this was to post on Meta. See https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/69495/revisions

Comment: I meant to this question which is to discuss the addition of new tags

Comment: I have now added the links to the question.

Comment: Minor point but the first question only has room for one more tag and the second and third questions don't have room for any more tags as they are at the cap of five tags.

Answer (score 6):

I am sure that there are a lot of interesting questions one could ask about Jersey. And I am also sure that there are a lot of interesting questions about Guernsey too. But so far nobody has asked any. So we don't need those tags (yet!).

The three questions mentioned here are neither specifically about Guernsey nor specifically about Jersey. They are all questions about the Channel Islands in general which apply to both of those bailiwicks equally. There is nothing in this questions which is specific only to Jersey and nothing that is specific only to Guernsey. We don't tag every question about the [united-kingdom](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kingdom) also with [england](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/england), [scotland](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scotland), [wales](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wales) and [northern-ireland](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/northern-ireland), do we? That would be pretty ridiculous, because we only have 5 tags per question. Which means we need to be careful with creating tags which are redundant. So we only add one of these country-tags in addition to the United Kingdom tag if the question is specifically about the status of one of these countries within the United Kingdom. We also use those country-tags on their own if the question is about an internal matter of one of these countries which isn't relevant to the United Kingdom in general.

<sub>(by the way: Did you notice that [england](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/england) doesn't even exist yet?)</sub>

So if we add a new tag to those three questions, that tag should be [british-channel-islands](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/british-channel-islands). But if we ever have more than one question about some matter which only applies to Guernsey, only applies to Jersey or which are about some matter between those two bailiwicks, then we can add those tags. Considering that those two "have the collective name Channel Islands only because of their geography" and that "they are actually separate countries each with its own government", it shouldn't be difficult to come up with some questions which do not always mention those two in the same sentence.

Comment: I guess England does not have a tag because it does not have its own legislature. british-channel-islands will have to do!

Comment: I guess England doesn't have a tag yet because nobody came up with two questions yet which are about England in particular.

Comment: Yes. But that may be because it doesn't have its own legislature so that there are few specifically English political questions (unless you go back to the 17th Century before the Act of Union)

Comment: @Nemo You don't need to have a legislature to have politically related questions.

Comment: No. But it helps!